# Generate a public link to a thumbnail from drobbox without downloading the image first

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm currently generating thumbnails from dropbox. When I generate one, I can get the URI.
But I was looking for a way to generate a link for the thumbnail without having do download the thumbnail, meaning just ask dropbox to generate a url to this thumbnail. Is this possible somehow? I'm using the core API.

The flow should be something like: From my server I generate a request to dropbox based on a users credentials to generate the thumbnail url. I can then forward this link to my user (browser client) where the thumbnail is then requested. It's ok for the link to only be temporary like 4 hours or so.

What I'm looking for is actual a combination of thumbnail and shares, looking at the core API

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this isn't possible with the Dropbox API. The [/thumbnails](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#thumbnails) call only gives you the content, and has no option to return a URL instead, and the [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media) call does return a URL, but only for the full file.

Comment: Yeah this was also the answer I got from twitter. Really hope this will be added to the API: Could im scenarios like the one I'm looking into move load from my server to my clients.